# Change of coordinates in Shannon entropy

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, entropy, change-of-variable

Let's say I've a probability distribution $f(x)$ for the variable $x$. With a change of variable to $y$, I can find the probability distribution for $y$: $g(y) = f(x)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|$.

The entropy should be: $$S = \int f(x)\log(f(x))dx=\int g(y)\log(g(y))dy$$

But now, in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.3390%2Fe12030578) [[NIHMS480577](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3891802)], eq 20. It is said that the entropy is coordinate dependent:

$$S' = \int f(x)\log(f(x))dx = \int f(x(y))\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|\log(f(x(y)))dy = \int g(y)\log(f(x(y)))dy$$

And of course $S'\neq S$. Something is wrong right? Care must be taken when we average a probability distribution?

Comment: If I apply the variable transformation I get $S=\int_a^b f(x)\log f(x)\,dx=\int_{y(a)}^{y(b)}g(y)\log\Big(g(y)\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)\,dy$ which is not what you thought that it should be.

Comment: In other words: you can replace $f(x)dx$ by $g(y)dy$ but to handle the naked $f(x)$ inside $\log$ you can only write $x$ as $x(y)$ (as that paper does) or $f(x)$ as $g(y)(dy/dx)$.

Comment: I see. Then the entropy is coordinate dependent? Because for the first equality, I didn't use any variable transformation, I just assumed (for no good reason?) that the entropy was dependent on the probability distribution, whatever the coordinates system used...

Comment: There is no doubt that the *Shannon entropy* can change under a change of variables. Just apply calculus. The paper is however interesting (will read) as it makes the convincing statement that *thermodynamic entropy* of a physical system must be invariant under a coordinate change. On PSE you can find many posts dealing with different concepts of entropy.