# Change of parameter in an integral of two functions

Tags: functions, coordinate-systems

A change of parametrization yields:

$$
\int f(x) dx \to \int f(y(x))  \frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int f(y) dy
$$

But I cannot work out how to do it when dealing with a product of two functions. Intuitively, I expected the following:

$$
\int h(x)g(x) dx \to \int h(y(x))  \frac{dy}{dx} g(y(x))  \frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int h(y) g(y(x))\frac{dy}{dx}  dy 
$$

But I cannot get rid of the dy/dx term.

Can anyone show how to do it?

Comment: It is, you are doing it wrong. Let me say it this way: the jacobian term is born from the $dy$, not from the functions.

Comment: @tommy1996q So how is it done?

Comment: @tommy1996q I took this information from this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Properties Perhaps it is incorrect?

Comment: Do you know how to integrate $\int \sin x\,\cos x\,dx$ by a change of variables? Hint: $y=\sin x\,,\;dy/dx=\cos x\,.$ How would you then handle the case $h(x)=g(x)=\sin x\,?$

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, I know the trick works because one is the derivative of the other. In this case however g(x) is not the derivative of h(x).

Comment: @KurtG. The case ℎ()=()=sin entails $\int sin^2 x dx = x/2 - (\sin 2x)/4 + c$. However I am not trying to integrate here. I am trying to demonstrate parameter invariance of certain integrals.

Comment: What is parameter invariance if not getting the same integral after a change of variables? We seem to agree on $\int \sin x\,\cos x\,dx\,.$ The case with "two" functions that I meant was $\int \sin x\,\sin x\,\cos x\,dx\,.$ In short: you never have to use $dy/dx$ more than once.

Comment: @KurtG. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545036/change-of-coordinates-in-shannon-entropy, they give an example of an integral that fails a change of parameter.

Comment: I commented on that question you just found and vaguely remember having read the paper that triggered that question. Now: we know how apply calculus for as many functions in the integral as we want. What is your question? Please elaborate.

Comment: @KurtG. My question is: Is the product of two functions invariant with respect to a change of variable. It appears that in general, the answer is no - correct?

Comment: Even the integral of a single function is not invariant with respect to a change of variables when you don't have a $dy/dx$ term at hand.

Comment: Now I see the relationship with that entropy question. You are right. The answer is no just as it was no over there.

Comment: @KurtG. But if I do the quotient and a product of two functions, then it always works. $\int f(x)/g(x) dx \to \int h(y(x)) dy/dx \frac{ f(y(x))  dy/dx} { g(y(x)) dy/dx} dx = \int h(y) \frac{ f(y) } { g(y) } dy$. Kinda weird

Comment: When do do that you should not replace $f(x)$ with $f(\color{red}{y}(x))$. This is abuse of notation. Better to call the second one, say, $F(y)$. How do you go from $f/g$ to $h\,f/g\,?$ I don't get that.

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry, from $\int h(x) \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx \to \int \tilde{h}(y)\frac{\tilde{f}(y)}{\tilde{g}(y)}dy$. The relative entropy is coordinate invariant and uses the triple structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Properties

Comment: I see. Nice and interesting. Not weird at all I think.

Comment: @KurtG. Could you have a look at this related question in the physics stackexchange https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/754961/the-average-of-a-continuous-value-overlineo-int-ox-rhox-dx-but-co. I think the person who provided the only answer got it wrong because it contradicts our discussion here. Can you weight in please?

Comment: @Anon21 . Will try. Might take some time though.

Comment: @KurtG. Awesome! thank you.