# Counter intuitive result : a change of parameter in a product of functions not parameter invariant?

Tags: integration, coordinate-systems

Say I have this function

$$
\int f(x) dx
$$

I now change $f(x)$ with $g(y) = f(x) \frac{dx}{dy}$

$$
\int g(y)\frac{dy}{dx}dx = \int g(y) dy
$$

So far, so good?

---

Say I have

$$
\int f(x) f(x) dx
$$

With the same change I have

$$
\int  g(y)\frac{dy}{dx}  g(y)\frac{dy}{dx}dx = \int  g(y)\frac{dy}{dx}  g(y)dy
$$

The conclusion is that the integral $\int f(x) f(x) dx$ is NOT coordinate invariant.

---

I have to say I am extremely surprised by this. Can anyone explain in an intuitive manner why this is the case?

Comment: $f(x)f(x)$ is a different function from $f(x)$. I don’t know what to call what you did, but it wasn’t a change of variables.

Comment: @DavidK I believe its called "defining a new function".

Comment: Yes, the part where you wrote $f(x)f(x)$ defined a new function. That’s the first thing I said. It was what you did afterward that was a new invention.

Comment: @DavidK I replaced f(x) with g(y)dy/dx, everytime f(x) appeared. This poster does the same here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545036/change-of-coordinates-in-shannon-entropy

Comment: Anon, $\,f(x)\mathrm dx=g(y)\mathrm dy\;$ does not imply $\;f^2(x)\mathrm dx=g^2(y)\mathrm dy\,,\;$
indeed if the signed area of the region bounded by the graph of a function $\,f(x)\,$ and the horizontal axis is equal to the region bounded by the graph of another function $\,g(y)\,$ and the horizontal axis, in general it does not imply that the same thing happens with $\,f^2(x)\,$ and $\,g^2(y)\,$, in fact their signed areas could be different. I think that a intuitive manner to explain why the integral $\,\int f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx\,$ is not coordinate invariant, is to think about the areas.

Comment: Notice that things don't work out well for https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4545036/139123 either. The formula usually called "change of variables" for an integral is not just replacing some function $f(x)$ by $g(y)\frac{dy}{dx}.$ It's an operation on the entire integral. If your integrand is $f(x)f(x)$ then you need a substitution for $f(x)f(x),$ not $f(x).$

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for clarifying. It also appears there is a triple product $\int h(x) \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}  dx \to \int \tilde{h}(y(x)) |dy/dx| \frac{\tilde{f}(y(x)) |dy/dx| }{\tilde{g}(y(x)) |dy/dx|} dx =  \int \tilde{h}(y) \frac{\tilde{f}(y) }{\tilde{g}(y)} dy$. This always works. For instance the relative entropy uses it to achieve parameter invariance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Properties. Can you share any insights on that one?